cy.matchImageSnapshot not taking snapshot of specified height and width
I'm attempting to take a snapshot in Cypress with dimensions of 500 pixels for both height and width. I've updated the relevant settings accordingly, but unfortunately, Cypress is still saving the screenshot with dimensions of 1000 x 1000 pixels if the image doesn't exist.
Am I doing something wrong?
cy.viewport(500,500);
cy.matchImageSnapshot(`snapshotName`);

Command.ts:
import { addMatchImageSnapshotCommand } from '@simonsmith/cypress-image-snapshot/command';

addMatchImageSnapshotCommand({
  failureThreshold: 0.0,
  failureThresholdType: 'percent',
});

Cypress.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin } from '@simonsmith/cypress-image-snapshot/plugin';

export default defineConfig({
  viewportHeight: 500,
  viewportWidth: 500,
  component: {
    viewportHeight: 500,
    viewportWidth: 500,
    devServer: {
      framework: 'react',
      bundler: 'webpack',
    },
    setupNodeEvents(on) {
      addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin(on);
    },
  },
});

